# I would like to know how do I convert the following lambda expression to a for-each loop:for java1.7 version

Tags: java, lambda, java-7

```
public static UserPrinciple build(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role ->
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name())
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new UserPrinciple(
            user.getId(),
            user.getName(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities
    );
}
```

I would like to know how do I convert the following lambda expression to a for-each loop for java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a normal for-loop:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities  = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specific syntax or properties of *role*, but this is how you would convert the lambda into a for loop.

```
public static UserPrinciple build(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name());
    }

    return new UserPrinciple(
            user.getId(),
            user.getName(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities
    );
}
```